# Solving linear equations in python with the answers restricted to 0/1

Tags: python

(My previous posting has just been closed. However, I cannot see what's inappropriate with the question.)

I'm dealing with a linear equations-solving problem, in which the value for each variable is either 0 or 1.
Hopefully, I would like to develop a solver that can tell whether the value for each variable is ***definitely*** 0 or 1. For the final output, the value would be assigned to the variable if it is solved; otherwise it would be assigned *None*.

For example, the inputs of 
***a*** + ***b*** + ***c*** = 1
***b*** + ***c*** = 1
should generate the outputs of
{***a***=0, ***b***=None, ***c***=None}

And the inputs of
***a*** + ***b*** + 2***c*** + ***d*** = 2
***a*** + ***d*** = 1
should give
{***a***=None, ***b***=1, ***c***=0, ***d***=None}

As far as I know, there already exist some general linear solvers in python (e.g. numpy.linalg.solve). Is it possible to utilize them and with modifications? If no, what is the recommended approach instead?
Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is very close. `np.linalg.solve(a,b)` can only be used, if `a` is square and of full-rank, i.e., all rows (or, equivalently, columns) must be linearly independent. Otherwise use for instance `lstsq` for the least-squares best "solution" of the system/equation.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
B = np.array([1, 1])
X = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)[0] #only interested of the best solution
###solution for [a, b, c]: 
###[-1.11022302e-16  5.00000000e-01  5.00000000e-01]

A = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]])
B = np.array([2, 1])
X = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)[0]
###solution for [a, b, c, d]: 
###[0.5 0.2 0.4 0.5]
```